# LinqPad "Auto Track Execution" and "Jump to Execution Point" ?

Tags: linqpad

What is LinqPad "Auto Track Execution" and "Jump to Execution Point" ? How to use them, if you can give an detail example would be great appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a detailed example, but it illustrates the feature. If you have an script like

```
 "1".Dump();
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 "2".Dump();
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 "3".Dump();
 ...
```

With Auto-track Execution enabled, you will get a yellow arrow pointing to each line as it is being executed.

With Auto-track Execution disabled, you can use the 'Jump to Execution Point' menu option or shortkey (Ctrl-Shift-J) to make the cursor jump to the currently executing line.

However Auto-track does not scroll/re-position automatically, so if the current line is not visible you need to use the 'Jump to Execution Point' to get it displayed.

Comment: Thanks Sgmoore! This is what I need it.